# Convert query result to byte array

Tags: sqlite, powershell, type-conversion

I am using [PSSQLite](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PSSQLite) module to read a database, though it returns an array of type object

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

I'd like to convert that to a byte array, I tried casting it but all I get back is errors, any suggestions?

This is my query

```psh
$value = Invoke-SqliteQuery -DataSource $filePath -Query "SELECT data FROM table" |
         Format-Table -HideTableHeaders
```

**EDIT:**
The output data is in the following format:

```
{1, 0, 0, 0, 208, 140, 157, 223, 1 ...}
```

Essentially the numbers are meant to be byte values, thus the output would be

```
1 0 0 0 208 140 ...
```

Comment: Show sample query results, show the desired output, show the code you used for the conversion attmpts, and show the errors those attempts produced. General advice: don't use `Format-*` cmdlets on data that is subject to further processing. The `Format-*` cmdlets are for output formatting.

Comment: Hey Ansgar,
thank you for your reply. I've added some additional information. Also, regarding the Format-* cmdlets, is there another way to get rid of the header?

Comment: How to get rid of headers depends on the data type of the query result. What is the output of `(Invoke-SqliteQuery -DataSource $filePath -Query "SELECT data FROM table").GetType()`?

Comment: IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                         
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                         
True     False    PSCustomObject                           System.Object

Comment: By the way, I was able to save the output to a file, manually remove "{" and "}", then load it as a string, convert to array casted as [byte] by splitting it on ", " and the rest of the script worked as expected

Comment: Which properties does the object have? (`Invoke-SqliteQuery ... | Get-Member -MemberType Properties`)

Comment: Name           MemberType   Definition                                
----           ----------   ----------                                
data NoteProperty System.Byte[] data=System.Byte[]

Hmmm .. interestingly enough it shows that it's a byte array? O_o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the properties of the query result object something like this should produce the desired result:

```
$filePath = '...'
$query    = 'SELECT data FROM table'

Invoke-SqliteQuery -DataSource $filePath -Query $query |
  Select-Object -Expand data
```